# Including files from NuGet into my project

Tags: sass, nuget, nuget-package

I have a NuGet wrapping a Razor Library (RCL), with .NET 7, that has images under `wwwroot` and SCSS files on a root folder called `Scss`. I am referencing this NuGet from my Blazor Webassembly 7. I can reference the images from my NuGet using the `_content` prefix and this is working as expected.

In my Blazor project, I have WebCompiler that will take some local SCSS files and combine them with the ones coming from the NuGet under the `Scss` folder to form CSS.

I am unable to get the Scss from NuGet to be copied to my Blazor project, I am getting a link to the files in `C:\Users\[username]\.nuget\packages\myprojecttheme\1.0.0` instead.

Below is my NuSpec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProjectTheme</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="wwwroot\**" target="content\" />
        <file src="Scss\**" target="contentFiles\any\any\Scss\" copyToOutput="true" />
    </files>
</package>
```

How can I have the actual files from the Scss folder being copied to my project rather than a link to them?

I am thinking of copying the files in a post build, but I am looking for a built in NuGet behavior.